# How to get CAST working correctly with division

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, window-functions

I am working with SSMS 2014.

My sample code is as follows:

```
select name
      ,family
      ,group
      ,mcount
      ,icount
      ,(cast(icount as demical(10,2)) / cast(mcount as decimal(10,2))) as per_unit 
from ( select distinct 
           mc.name
          ,mc.family
          ,mc.group
          ,sum(mc.mcount) over (partition by mc.name) as mcount
          ,sum(ic.icount) over (partition by ic.name) as icount
      from mc
      join ic
         on ic.num1 = mc.num1) as a
order by mcount desc
```

The first record of my per unit column is supposed to divide 76 / 50. this should = 1.52, however, it returns 1.5200000000000.  the second record divides 52/28 and returns 1.8571428571428.

I am looking for 2 decimal places. I read to cast as decimal(10,2) however this seems to not be working.

What am I doing wrong??
thank you

Comment: demical is spelled wrong...

Comment: When you devide 76 and 50 - both of them have no decimal places at all. But result has it. Why do you think the result will have the same quantity of decimals as arguments?

Comment: you know...i asked because i didn't know. i am trying to be polite here. but if you are going to ask me this question i obviously do not have the answer to...because i'm asking the above questions. do not post anything at all. if you have something to contribute like the people who are trying to help below, by all means go for it...otherwise...don't post as you are not helping anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your division to either:

```
cast((cast(icount as demical(10,2)) / cast(mcount as decimal(10,2))) as decimal(10,2)) as per_unit
```

or ideally, assuming your `icount` and `mcount` are also `decimal` values:

```
cast(icount / mcount as decimal(10,2)) as per_unit
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly!  i have less than 15 rep so i cannot up-vote. but this is exactly what i needed for this (the top example).

Comment: @RyanOtto  If this was the right answer for your question, for the benefit of other SO users, please accept it as the answer.  This is different to upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the result of the division.

Change this

```
(cast(icount as demical(10,2)) / cast(mcount as decimal(10,2))) as per_unit
```

to this

```
cast(icount  / mcount  as decimal(10,2)) as per_unit
```

If `icount` & `mcount` are int keep the existing casts.

Comment: thank you for your answer - this gave me 1.00 and 2.00 instead of 1.52 but it was on the right path - and i think i can use it for something else!! so it was definitely helpful - i also did not indicate the column formats ...which i should have done! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One More cast will give desired result

```
 cast((cast(icount as demical(10,2)) / cast(mcount as decimal(10,2))) as Decimal(10,2)) per_unit
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! this also is similar to the top answer above and works perfectly!!! again, as i have less that 15 rep i cannot upvote but this works out exactly how i need!!!